# Excel Programming - If Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have coded on C# before and know all of the basics to do with loops and statements. 
I have been trying to make a simple IF statement on excel but a very unhelpful error comes up every time I try and run it. 
I was wondering if anyone would be able to point out what I'm doing wrong here -

I'm just trying to output a "Yes" If cell h14 is greater than 250 OR less than 250 AND cell I14 is greater than 0.15 OR less than -0.15 else output "No"

This is what I came up with but it doesn't seem to work:
`IF((H14>=250 OR H14<=-250) AND (I14 >= 0.15 OR I14 <= -0.15),"Yes", "No")`

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AND` and `OR` are in the wrong place:

```
IF(AND(OR(H14>=250,H14<=-250),OR(I14 >= 0.15,I14 <= -0.15)),"Yes", "No")
```

The `AND()` and `OR()` statements are set up the same:

```
AND(criteria1,criteria2,...)
```

So we nest each inside the other.

As per your comment to deal with errors, wrap the whole in `IFERROR()`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(OR(H14>=250,H14<=-250),OR(I14 >= 0.15,I14 <= -0.15)),"Yes", "No"),"")
```

Change the `""` at the end to what ever you want.  As it stands it will return an empty cell when there is an error.

Comment: Saviour! Thank you very much works a treat, I think I understand how it works now!

Comment: @mot375 please come back in 10 minutes and mark as correct.

Comment: Would you be able to quickly explain to me how to embed an IF x= Error.Type(#DIV/0!) then output.... on Excel?

Comment: @mot375 not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: So if the contents of the cell displays #DIV/0! I can output something else?